# JSON data in an iOS widget?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Is it possible to call a JSON API from within a view controller for a today widget and have it present data?

I’ve searched for days trying to get a straightforward answer but there seems to be no answer!

I prefer using Alamofire and all the pods are correctly set up in the Podfile.

Comment: You mean you have the pods set up correctly in the Podfile already?

Comment: Hi yes I do and they can be called within the widget controller

Comment: It is entirely possible but your question is missing info that would help us help you better. Assuming you are already doing this in your main app, the logic is exactly the same for the widget. What have you tried or what kind of problems are you running into?